# Is there a way to take an Extension License from another user in ArcMap/ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, license

I'm using ArcMap 10.1 and need a specific extension that's activated on another user's machine.  Is there a script or other tool available to re-claim this license?

Comment: is the other user on a floating license or node locked? if floating license then yes, node-locked no.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's a floating license.  Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here are the typical reasons a license is not available:**

User with Extension needs to deactivate the extension and close ArcGIS.
License Server (Desktop Administrator) should show the license has returned

Then Enable the Extension in ArcGIS on the user who needs the extension.

```
You have not licensed the extension from Esri, so it's not on your License Manager.
All the available concurrent use licenses for this extension are currently in use by other users.
The license has timed out and needs to be renewed.
You have not borrowed the required extension license from your license manager before disconnecting your machine from the network.
```

If all the concurrent use licenses for the extension are currently in use by other users, you won't be able to use the extension until a license becomes available.

Full Details

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018900000002000000

Comment: Thank you for the resource.  I had read this, but have also heard there's a script out there to fill this need.  Probably just wishful thinking!

Comment: Do you mean deactivating another users' extension and then checking it out yourself?

Comment: I'd hate to deactivate her.  She'll need to use it at some point.  I just need it now.  No way for me to get to her machine though.

Answer (score 2):

You used to be able to do this with the `lmutil lmremove` command, but this command no longer works with ArcGIS 10.1 (or I think anything since 9.1).

A minorly disruptive alternative is to start and stop the license service. Stop the service, wait a few seconds, then start it and immediately check out the license you need.
Current users will get a license server warning, but will not actually be booted (except for the user whose license you took).